# Find element that doesn't have a specific key property in JS objects array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, javascript-objects

i have an array :

```
[
 0 {
     Id : 01
     country : "Algery"
     name: "Amnesty"
    },
 1  {
     Id : 02
     country : "USA"
     name: "Alarmy"
    },
 2 {
     Id : 03
     country : "Alaska"
    }

]
```

And i want to find in this list the object that has not the property "Name".

I tried by doing `myArray.find((pers) => !(pers.name));`

But it doesn't work.. anyone have an idea here?

Comment: ```myArray.filter(item=>item.name===undefined)``` should do the trick

Comment: That code works: https://jsfiddle.net/2j3n6auf/

Comment: @ikhvjs Only because `undefine` is not defined :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```js
const arr = [{ Id: 01, country: "Algery", name: "Amnesty" }, { Id:02, country: "USA", name: "Alarmy" }, { Id: 03, country:"Alaska" }];

console.log(arr.find(obj => !('name' in obj)));
```

Comment: This is a great copy of  [Nina's answer from 3 minutes before you...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67739545/215552)

Comment: @HereticMonkey While I understand what you are saying, I didn't see his/her post before I posted mine.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine only for falsy `name`. To check if a property exists, you could take the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).

```js
const
    array = [{ Id: 01, country: "Algery", name: "Amnesty" }, { Id: 02, country: "USA", name: "Alarmy" }, { Id: 03, country: "Alaska" }];

console.log(array.find(person => !('name' in person)));
```

This approach returns only the first found item. For getting all items, you could apply [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for getting an array.

Answer (score 0):

Beside above mention ways, one more way to achieve this is by using hasOwnProperty method

For your reference :

```
for ( var key in jsonArray) {
  if (!jsonArray[key].hasOwnProperty("name")) {
      console.log(jsonArray[key]);
  }
}
```